# How to not to display (echo) a default value in case no info is received?

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi guys i got to fix some things on a website, and i got to fix this problem, there is a form in which there is a field to display the age of a person, and the age is calculated by subtracting the date the person was born (this value you have input on the field) minus the current year and but the problem is if you dont have the person's the date of birth it shows by default the current year cause the variable that holds the persons date of birth is = 0 cause nothing was inserted so, it shows on the page 2014 years old, so what i want it if nothing is displayed then dont display that field at all, and else{} solution  is needed so any ideas how to solve it here is the code.

```
if (strcmp ( $title , "Año de nacimiento" ) ==-1)
{
    if($edad!=1)
    {
        $fecha = date("Y");
        $edad=$fecha-$c;

        echo "<div class='uk-grid' data-uk-grid-margin='' >";
        echo "<div class='uk-width-medium-7-10'><b>";
                  echo JText::_('ADSMANAGER_CAMPO_EDAD');
                  echo "</b></div>";
        echo "<div class='uk-width-medium-3-10'>$edad a&ntilde;os";
        echo "</div></div>";

        $edad=1;
    }
}
```

By the way "Año de nacimiento" is the year of birth, $edad is the age gotten by the subtracting the year of birth - current year (2014)  of course i have to put and else {} any ideas how to solve this riddle?

Comment: `strcmp() == -1`? Is that going to do what you want it to do? `== 0` would be a match.

Comment: i didnt create this code, i got hirred to fix some stuff. But what u mean if i implement == 0 instead of == -1 then if nothing is introduced on the year of birth field, then the field is not displayed at all, cause that is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys this worked for me guys, in order to give the order of not displaying the age field in case is not given by the admnistrator, what i did is this:

```
$fecha = date("Y");
 $edad = $fecha - $c;

if($edad!= $fecha){same logic as before}
```

As you can see i put the age calculation before the if{} so if the age calculation is not equal to the current date, then display the field with the age, else would mean that the age is the same (current date is the default age when date of birth is not given) as the current date so dont display anything or since it was not given dont display it.  Thanx anyways guys i am proud to have solved this by my own!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$edad = $fecha - ($c ? $c : 2000);
```

That `2000` should be a reasonable default - in this case, it would default their age to 14 years, so... try `1990` perhaps. Whatever works best for your situation.

In newer versions of PHP, you can do:

```
$edad = $fecha - ($c ?: 2000);
```

Comment: dont understand this :2000 or 1990 would subtract the current year (2014) and as a solution display a lower number like if i place :1990 it would display as default age 24 years old, and i dont want that i want if no year of birth is inserted then dont display that field at all...how can i do that, thanx?